# Maximising directional derivative of a polynomial in 3 variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning

I am a beginner in multivariable calculus and had started reading Apostol. I have solved all the exercises in the portions I have covered, except one problem.

> Find values of the constants $a,b,c$ such that the directional derivative of $f(x,y,z)=axy^2+byz+cx^3z^2$ at the point $(1,2,-1)$ attains a maximum value of $64$ in a direction parallel to $z$-axis.

I am not sure that I understand the wording of the problem. I know the definition of directional derivative at a point $a$ in the direction of a vector $y$: it is the derivative $f'(a;y)$ where $y$ is a unit vector. So what I think is, since $y$ is a unit vector parallel to $z$-axis in our case, we must have $y=(0,0,1)$.

Therefore, we need to obtain the partial derivative $D_zf(x,y,z)=by+2cx^3z$, at $(1,2,-1)$ hence $D_zf(1,2,-1)=2(b-c)$.

How do I maximize this quantity (surely the supremum is infinity?)? I believe I am not understanding the problem at all.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directional derivatives are maximized when they are taken in the direction of the gradient (to prove this, use Cauchy-Schwarz). We have:
$$\nabla f(x,y,z) = (ay^2 + 3cx^2 z^2, 2axy + bz, by + 2cx^3z),$$
$$\nabla f(1,2,-1) = (4 a+3 c,4 a-b,2 b-2 c)$$
We want this to be parallel to $(0,0,1)$, i.e. we require
$$(4 a+3 c,4 a-b,2 b-2 c) = (0,0,k)$$
for some $k \in \mathbb{R^+}$. That is, we require
\begin{align*}
4a  + 3c &= 0, \\
4a - b &= 0, \\
b - c &= k',
\end{align*}
where $k' = k/2$ (the constant doesn't matter). Solving, $c = -k'/4$, $b = 3k'/4$, and $a = 3k'/16$. It remains to find $k'$. We also know the maximum directional derivative is $|| \nabla f(1,2,-1) ||$ (this also follows from the proof I mentioned in the first line). But this is easy, since we set the gradient equal to $(0,0,k) = (0,0,2k')$. Then
$$|| \nabla f(1,2,-1) || = ||(0,0,2k')|| = 2k' = 64$$
so $k' = 32$. Plugging this into the relations we found earlier,
$$\boxed{(a,b,c) = (6, 24, -8)}.$$

---

**Thm.** Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function. The directional derivative $D_{\vec{u}}f$ at $x$ is maximized when $\vec{u}$ is in the direction of the gradient $\nabla f$. In this case, $D_{\vec{u}}f = || \nabla f(x) ||.$

**Proof.** Since $f$ is differentiable, for any unit vector $\vec{u}$, we can write
$$D_\vec{u} f = \nabla f \cdot \vec{u}.$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$D_\vec{u} f = \nabla f \cdot \vec{u} \leq ||\nabla f||\;||\vec{u}|| = ||\nabla f||$$
with equality if and only if $\nabla f = k \vec{u}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R^+}.$

Comment: Really great, except that I observe that you wrote $||(0,0,2k')||=2k'$, which is wrong, since you did not assume $k'>0$. Hence you should have $||(0,0,2k')||=2|k'|$ which then can be used to generate a second set of solutions $(a,b,c)=(-6,-24,8)$.

Comment: I wrote that $k \in \mathbb{R^+}$. If $k$ were negative then the gradient is in the direction of the negative z-axis, which isn't what OP wanted.

Comment: "...parallel to $z$-axis...". And yes, sorry that I missed out you wrote $k\in\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Yeah I suppose the other answerer and I assumed the positive z axis by virtue of the wording of the beginning of the question.

Comment: usually in the discussion of vectors, it's presumed parallel means $a\cdot b=|a||b|$ while antiparallel refers to $a\cdot b=-|a||b|$

Answer (score 1):

The directional derivative is maximized in the direction of greatest change, i.e. the *gradient*, given by $\operatorname{grad} f=\left(ay^2+3cx^2z^2,2axy+bz,by+2cx^3z\right)$. Now, at $(1,2,-1)$ the gradient is as follows: $$(\operatorname{grad} f)\big|_{(1,2,-1)}=\left(4a+3c,4a-b,2b-2c\right)$$So we expect the $4a+3c=4a-b=0$ while $2b-2c=64$. This gives $b+3c=0,b-c=32$ so $4c=-32\implies c=-8$. This ultimately gives $b=c+32=24$ and $4a=24\implies a=6$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. :)